# Does Tensorflow Lite support the TimeDistributed layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently working with a Keras model with **TimeDistributed**, Conv2D and Bidirectional(LSTM) layers (code example below) and I'm trying to convert to TF Lite.

```
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))(input_a)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1)))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
x = Model(inputs=input_a, outputs=x)

y = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))(input_b)
y = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='tanh', padding='same'))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1)))(y)
y = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(y)
y = Model(inputs=input_b, outputs=y)

combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])

z = Bidirectional(LSTM(512))(combined)
z = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(z)
```

The **conversion is actually successful** (code below), but I experience a strong accuracy drop when testing the TF Lite model.

```
def representative_data_gen():
  for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(predictors_train).batch(1).take(100):
    input_value_1 = numpy.array(input_value[:,:,:4,:], dtype=numpy.float32)
    input_value_2 = numpy.array(input_value[:,:,4:,:], dtype=numpy.float32)
    yield [input_value_1, input_value_2]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen

converter.experimental_new_converter=True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS, tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False

converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()
```

**Since I can't find the TimeDistributed layer on the supported operation list but the conversion is successful anyway, I asked myself if this layer could actually be the problem.**

Any hint or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In case somebody is having the same problem: I've done some debugging in the past few days and the problem seems to be elicited not by the TimeDistributed layer, but by the combination of TimeDistributed layers with Conv2D inside and an LSTM right after.

I'm still analyzing the problem in-depth... Update ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Try first a float version without quantization to see if accuracy is good. If there is a drop  even with float, then file a github issue for TFLite team.

If the drop is in the quantized version, then you can start by inspecting which layer(s) are the culprit by using the [QuantizationDebugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_debugger).

Comment: I already tried the float32 version, the accuracy drop is there... Thank you for your help, I wasn't aware of the Debugger existence!!